# I installed a reflashed ecm in a 2013 Chrysler Town and Country and it won't start

Tags: chrysler

I forgot to disconnect the battery before starting. When I turn key on, it is asking for security code.

Comment: You need to change the VIN number in the PCM to match yours. If that has already been done then you are having other issues. What is asking for security code? Or are you using a scanner trying to program a key and you're talking about the PIN code it wants? Is this US region or elsewhere in the world?

Comment: Was it reflashed to expect a code? If not then you might need to get it flashed and matched to the car.